# XCode custom segue class stuck

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

this question might seem a little weird, but I can't wrap my head around why this is happening.

What I did was I renamed a custom segue class, and reflected it in the storyboard under 'custom class', but it still tries to call the old one.

I have cleaned the build folder and searched the project for the old custom class name and it does not find anything in xcode at least. I look inside the storyboard file, it's not there either.

Even if I delete the custom segue all toghether I get:

```
'Could not find a segue class named 'xxxxxxxxx''
```

The thing is I cannot understand from where it gets 'xxxxxxxxx' above, it is not in the storyboard file or in the code..

```
[[[self view] viewWithTag:1] resignFirstResponder];
```

When I debug this is where it goes to thread kill showing the error. I have removed all the outlets, events and segues on the textfield. I have no custom segue using 'xxxxxxxxx' as a class anywhere.

Is there any other thing I can do to clean the project more thoroughly? Where to begin?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the app on the device/reset the simulator? Have you checked whether the segue class is defined properly in the property in storyboard?

Comment: I am not adept at mac overall, but I tried to search the entire hard drive for any files containing the class name, and it finds nothing.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I reset the simulator settings and content, set the locale, but when I run it I get the wrong storyboard (I get the English one even tough I have set the simulator to Swedish) the English storyboard is not finished and now I can't get it to run the one I got in the sv.lproj folder. Is this a clue? @nhahtdh

Comment: I just confirmed in the code that the locale is Swedish, but it does not engage the Swedish storyboard any longer. Hm.

Comment: My storyboard had lost its 'target membership' but the old one remained on the simulator until I reset it.

THANK YOU nhahtdh!!

I cannot answer myself for 7 hours, you do it if you want delicious karma :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is to reset the storyboard target membership, then reset the simulator.

Comment: God, it took me two hours of struggling for this tiny click! Thank you very much, you saved my day!

Comment: I have the same issue, and for me reset simulator does not help

Comment: @János: The solution differs from one case to another. Have you tried the suggestion in the other answer?

Comment: @János If it is still actual, or anybody else wonders, I also had to reset the storyboard target membership before resetting the simulator.

Comment: I did then same, later I deleted app from simulator then installed again, it worked. Thanks nhahtdh

Answer (score 76):

This was what worked for me - I had to select the segue in interface builder and set the module from "None" to my project name, which appeared in the dropdown.

Comment: Helped me too, but how to avoid this?

Comment: makes sense, however, the module dropdown is grayed-out.  If I attach a custom class, it is enabled but does not fix for me.

Comment: @MihaelIsaev File a radar 

Comment: For me, it occurred when I changed product name. My custom segue still use the older name as its module name. I didn't know that the module name is from the product name by default.

Answer (score 6):

For others that came from the web searching for the answer: check if you have included implementation file in Build Phases. In my case, I had several targets and the second target was missing this implementation file.

Answer (score 4):

Check out this other SO question.  Answer to "Issue #1" by declaring the custom-seque-class to be and objective-c class

[Similiar SO Q&A - speaks to a flaw in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185345/custom-segue-in-swift)

Summary of answer:

```
@objc(CustomSequeLeft2Right)
class CustomSequeLeft2Right {
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: This.  The Swift name-mangling doesn't seem to consistently play nice with storyboards and this side-steps the issue entirely.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was i explicitly set the **"Class"** name in interface builder; which was not required. It is managed by Xcode and default to UIStoryboardSegue.