# Custom Segue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

```
@objc(SEPushNoAnimationSegue)
class SEPushNoAnimationSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform () {
      self.sourceViewController.navigationController.pushViewController(self.destinationViewController, animated:false)
    }
}
```

In the above code, I have 2 questions:
1). it has a compile error:
'UINavigationController!' does not have a member named 'pushViewController'

But in that class, it did has a pushViewController method.

2). I have to add the annotation: @objc(SEPushNoAnimationSegue),
otherwise, in storyboard, it only recognize the random generated name, like, _tcxxxxSEPushNoAnimationSegue.

why these 2 issues happen here?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## Issue #1

UIStoryboardSegue has an irritating flaw: its sourceViewController and destinationViewController properties are typed as `AnyObject!` (that's the case even in Objective-C (Id type)) and not as `UIViewController`, as it should be.

That same flaw creates havoc in your perfect and simple code. Here's how to rewrite it in order to fix the compile errors:

```
@objc(SEPushNoAnimationSegue)
class SEPushNoAnimationSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform () {
        let src = self.sourceViewController as UIViewController
        let dst = self.destinationViewController as UIViewController
        src.navigationController.pushViewController(dst, animated:false)
    }
}
```

NOTE: Apple fixed this thing in iOS 9. `sourceViewController` and `destinationViewController` are now correctly declared as `UIViewController`.

## Issue #2

The Swift compiler stores its symbols using its own [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), and good ol' Objective-C does not recognize it in Xcode. Using an explicit `@obj()` solves the issue.

Comment: I got this: Can't unwrap Optional.None

Comment: explicit @objc() - great suggestion - that's what did it for me

Comment: the swift name convention has the purpose to avoid conflicts with others imports.

Comment: Just set the module of the specific Segue to your project in the Storyboard

Comment: This only worked for me when I added a question mark after navigationController. Otherwise it wouldn't compile.

Comment: I can't believe that just adding @objc(classname) in front of the class declaration makes it work... *facepalm*

Answer (score 5):

This works fine for me

```
@objc(SEPushNoAnimationSegue) class SEPushNoAnimationSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

override func perform() {
    let sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController as UIViewController
    let destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController as UIViewController

    sourceViewController.presentViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even Better:

```
import UIKit

class CustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController as UIViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0:

```
import UIKit

class CustomNoAnimationSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        if let navigation = source.navigationController {
            navigation.pushViewController(destination, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```