# Transition to a new View Controller in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I previously transistioned from one VC to another by:

1. Creating a button
2. Ctrl-drag the button to the new VC
3. Select Custom

That was it and it worked. Now however, I am trying this again on a new app and I am getting the error : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not perform segue with identifier '(null)'. A segue must either have a performHandler or it must override -perform.'
*** First throw call stack:

Is there something I need to add since Swift2.0?

Comment: maybe u want to add segue stuff to VC like `override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)` or `self.performSegueWithIdentifier` or create an `indentifier`for it....

Comment: Did you add an identifier in your identity inspector for your segue? I've got a video that goes over these steps, it might help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHG6tQYFU6I

Comment: No, and I've never done that before and it worked? I'm trying to work out what's changed? Thanks for the video but that goes a bit deeper and more complex than what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: if u choose `custom`, u have to give it `indentifier` and custom handler, if not, just choose `show` if u have Nav bar or `show modally`, that wont need to do anything else and just work

Comment: @Tj3n - thanks - that worked great :) Want to put it as an answer so I can approve it?

Comment: alright, glad to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `custom` segue type, u have to give it `indentifier` and `custom handler`, if not, choose `show` type if u have `Navigation Controller` or `show modally` type , that wont need to name or add anything else and it will just work

U can read more about `custom` segue [here](http://www.appcoda.com/custom-segue-animations/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185345/custom-segue-in-swift)